# I have a key for 2005 Nissan Xterra, what other models and/or years could this fit?

Tags: key

I would like to sell this key but I'm not sure what other models or years it may fit. Is there anyone who knows or knows where I could find out?

Comment: Is it a blank key that has not been cut?

Comment: No, it's a cut key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is useless.The number of possible lock combinations is in the thousands.The odds of finding a vehicle that it will fit is slightly less that picking the winning Lotto number.